# jQuery - keyup and iPad caret positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, email

I've had an issue where users are continually adding commas in our email field; to remedy this in the interim I was looking to convert comma input to a period.

**Now before anyone says *'commas are valid in email addresses'* i'm fully aware that this isn't a great solution... and i apologise in advance but i'm restricted to a single email address field and I can't add a second for validation purposes so...**

Now this works fine except for iPad. The 'keyup' event seems to move the caret positon in the input to the beginning; if I change it to 'keydown' it works as intended but the last keypress isn't converted

Code as follows:

```
<label>email: </label>
<input id="tb_Email" length="30"></input>
```

and JS:

```
$(document).ready(function (event) {

          $(document).delegate("#tb_Email", "keyup", function (event) {
              if (event.which === 188) {
                  var cleanedValue = $(this).val().replace(",", ".");
                  $(this).val(cleanedValue);
              }
          });
      });
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/JXVcm/1/

Does anyone have any suggestions to modify this code to work as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/JXVcm/10/).

HTML:

```
<label>email:</label>
<input id="tb_Email" length="30"></input>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function (event) {
    $(document).delegate("#tb_Email", "keyup", function (event) {
        if (event.which === 188) {
            var cleanedValue = $(this).val().replace(",", ".");
            $(this).val(cleanedValue);
            $(this).caretToEnd();
        }
    });

    //Set caret position easily in jQuery
    (function ($) {
        // Behind the scenes method deals with browser
        // idiosyncrasies and such
        $.caretTo = function (el, index) {
            if (el.createTextRange) {
                var range = el.createTextRange();
                range.move("character", index);
                range.select();
            } else if (el.selectionStart != null) {
                el.focus();
                el.setSelectionRange(index, index);
            }
        };

        // The following methods are queued under fx for more
        // flexibility when combining with $.fn.delay() and
        // jQuery effects.

        // Set caret to a particular index
        $.fn.caretTo = function (index, offset) {
            return this.queue(function (next) {
                if (isNaN(index)) {
                    var i = $(this).val().indexOf(index);

                    if (offset === true) {
                        i += index.length;
                    } else if (offset) {
                        i += offset;
                    }

                    $.caretTo(this, i);
                } else {
                    $.caretTo(this, index);
                }

                next();
            });
        };

        // Set caret to beginning of an element
        $.fn.caretToStart = function () {
            return this.caretTo(0);
        };

        // Set caret to the end of an element
        $.fn.caretToEnd = function () {
            return this.queue(function (next) {
                $.caretTo(this, $(this).val().length);
                next();
            });
        };
    }(jQuery));
```

I included small plugin code for position.

Comment: Boom... although lengthy it works (when you substitute CHARACTER in: `range.move("CHARACTER", index); `

Comment: Updated tested code: [http://jsfiddle.net/JXVcm/17/](http://jsfiddle.net/JXVcm/17/)